# Symfony2 organization: where to put entity functions that interact with database and other entities

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony

I've converted a PHP application over to Symfony2 and have yet another structural question...

In my old application I would have entity classes that might act upon other entity classes...for instance, I have a search class and a result class. A function like search->updateSearch() would operate upon the search class, and upon its child result class ($this->result->setFoo('bar'). This is just one example of an entity-related function that doesn't belong in Symfony2's entity class.

From what I can tell it seems like the most symfonyesque method would be to create a service, something along the lines of a searchHelper class, to which I could pass the entity manager, $search, and $result classes, and operate on them there.

Does that sound like the best course of action?

Thank you!

Comment: You may want to look at http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this scenario I use Model Managers, it's intended to be a business layer ORM agnostic interface for operating with entities. Something like:

```
<?php

/**
 * Group entity manager
 */
class GroupManager
{
    /**
     * Holds the Doctrine entity manager for database interaction
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * Holds the Symfony2 event dispatcher service
     * @var EventDispatcherInterface
     */
    protected $dispatcher;

    /**
     * Entity specific repository, useful for finding entities, for example
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher
     * @param EntityManager $em
     * @param string $class
     */
    public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher, EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->repository = $em->getRepository($class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Group
     */
    public function findGroupBy(array $criteria)
    {
        return $this->repository->findOneBy($criteria);
    }

    /**
     * @return Group
     */
    public function createGroup()
    {
        $group = new Group();

        // Some initialization or creation logic

        return $group;
    }

    /**
     * Update a group object
     *
     * @param Group $group
     * @param boolean $andFlush
     */
    public function updateGroup(Group $group, $andFlush = true)
    {
        $this->em->persist($group);

        if ($andFlush) {
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add a user to a group
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param Group $group
     * @return Membership
     */
    public function addUserToGroup(User $user, Group $group)
    {
        $membership= $this->em->getRepository('GroupBundle:Membership')
        ->findOneBy(array(
            'user'  => $user->getId(),
            'group' => $group->getId(),
        ));

        if ($membership && $membership->isActive()) {
            return null;
        } elseif ($membership && !$membership->isActive()) {
            $membership->setActive(true);

            $this->em->persist($membership);
            $this->em->flush();
        } else {
            $membership = new Membership();
            $membership->setUser($user);
            $membership->setGroup($group);

            $this->em->persist($membership);
            $this->em->flush();
        }

        $this->dispatcher->dispatch(
            GroupEvents::USER_JOINED_GROUP, new MembershipEvent($user, $group)
        );

        return $membership;
    }
```

And then the service definition:

```
<service id="app.model_manager.group" class="App\GroupBundle\Entity\GroupManager">
    <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher" />
    <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
</service>
```

You can inject the logger, mailer, router, or whichever other service you could need.

Take a look to FOSUserBundle managers, to get examples and ideas about how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using doctrines custom repository classes. You can check them out here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes

Basically they allow you to add custom logic above and beyond your basic entity. Also because they are basically an extension of the entity it makes it really easy to load them in and use their functions:

```
//Basic Entity File
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Namespace\Bundle\Repository\ProductRepo")
 */
class Product
{
    //...
}
```

Then the repo file for that entity:

```
//Basic Repo File
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepo extends EntityRepository
{
    public function updateSearch($passedParam)
    {
       // Custom query goes here
    }
}
```

Then from your controller you can load the repo and use the function:

```
//Controller file
class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function updateSearchAction()
    {
         $productRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Namespace\Bundle\Entity\Product');

         // Set $passedParam to what ever it needs to be

         $productRepo->updateSearch($passedParam);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Based upon Symfony2's documentation I'm not positive that Repositories are what I should be using, the book says: "You can think of a repository as a PHP class whose only job is to help you fetch entities of a certain class."

Since what I'm looking for is more than only fetching entities, I think the suggestion of Model Managers might be more applicable.

Great example of using custom repositories though...I plan to reference this later.